# Replace an iframe with an image from the iframe's source via jQuery

Tags: jquery, html, iframe, replace, entity-attribute-value

I *think* what I want to do is create a variable from an attribute's value so I can insert a new object using the variable as another attribute's value...

I have a media search site in an environment where my ability to configure the template for our search results page is restricted. Hovering on a search result displays the web page of the result in an iframe off to the side:
[image]

The the code for the content in the iframe includes the an image's URL as a link's href attribute, and I'd like to replace the iframe with an image using this href attribute value as its src attribute.

So, I want to get the value of `div.foo a`'s `href` attribute, and replace `iframe.bar` with `<img src="href from div.foo a"/>`

I have this notion that I can use jQuery to get and "store" the value of `div.bar`'s `href` attribute, replace `iframe.foo` with an `img`, and set the `img`'s `src` attribute's value to my stored `href` attribute value.

Help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to play with some Jquery and your I frame. For example try to reach to your iframe when it loads. And do your stuff.

**HTML:**

```
<iframe id="iframe1" src="http://www.sevenforums.com/attachments/browsers-mail/145092d1379294855t-multiple-web-pages-1-screen-page-untitled.png" width="100%" height="350">
  <p>Your browser does not support iframes.</p>
</iframe>

<input id="replace_iframe" type="button" value="Replace Iframe with Image" />
```

**Jquery/Javascript:**

```
$(function(){
    $("#iframe1").load(function(){

        var iframe_obj = this;
        var iframe_src = $(iframe_obj).attr("src");
        //Alerting Iframe Source
        alert(iframe_src);

        // If you want to replace THIS iframe with an IMAGE
        $( "#replace_iframe" ).click(function() {
          $(iframe_obj).replaceWith( "<img src='"+iframe_src+"' />" );
          //Removing Replace button Element
          $(this).remove();
        });

    });
});
```

**Working Example:**
http://jsfiddle.net/51uaw4k9/1/

Answer (score 0):

You could do something along the lines of:

```
    //retreive href
    href = $('.foo').attr('href');

    // set image source
    $('.bar').attr('src', href);
```

From what you're asking though it sounds like you'll want to change the `<iframe>` to `<img>` one way to do this is with:

```
    // get iframe's parent and change to image
    iframe = $('iframe.bar').parent();

    // change to image tag
    iframe.replaceWith( '<img class="bar">' );
```